# What particle (の；を) should I use between noun/verb and ～方 (買い方；歩い方 etc.)?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-の

I'm not sure of particles in these 3 sentences, especially this particle-の between noun/verb and ～方, are they OK? 
(If you see any other grammar mistake, you may let me know too.)

> 1）着物を着て**の**歩い方は何ですか。
>   2）飛行機の切符**の**買い方を教えてくれます。
>   3）写真**の**撮り方を忘れた。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

～のVerb(pre-masu form) + 方 is the set form. ～をVerb + 方 would be wrong.

As you need to use the pre-masu form, 歩い方 would be wrong. 歩き方 would be correct.

> 1）着物を着ての歩い方は何ですか

何 implies a specific thing, like asking 'What is the thing that is the way of walking while wearing a kimono.'

It might be better to separate the two thus:

> 着物を着て歩くのは難しいです。どうやって歩きますか？

If you still want to place them in the same sentence, I would go with:

> 着物を着て歩くのはどうやってやりますか。

or, as @immateur has suggested:

> 着物での歩き方はどのようにすればいいですか？

If you were to provide the English of what you want to say it might be helpful.

> 2）飛行機の切符の買い方をおしえてくれます

I don't see anything wrong with this sentence. If you are asking about the purchasing from a machine, it would be better to say 飛行機の切符販売機の使い方を教えてください。

> 3）写真の撮り方を忘れた。

This is fine.

Comment: I'm confused. Why would you replace を with が in sentence 3)? As far as I know 忘れる is a transitive verb.

Comment: "歩き方" is correct, as you suggested, but we don't say "歩くのやり方". We say, for example, "着物での歩き方はどのようにすればいいですか？".

Comment: @user3856370 I don't have a clear grammatical answer. Nothing to do with transitive/intrasitive. Just to shift focus from the act of forgetting to the thing which was forgotten. I will amend the answer to alleviate confusion.

Comment: @immateur  Thank you. I have taken the liberty of editing and adding your suggestion to the answer. Hope you don't mind.